# CollectionView cells Background changs when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, view, scroll, uicollectionview

In my app (keyboard extension) I set up a color scheme to change background color based on the theme (light/dark).
I created a collection view and I set its color with my color scheme. However if the collection view is scrollable, some buttons' color change after I scroll it.
How do I prevent it from happening?
This only happens in dark mode

This is how I setup my color scheme

```swift
enum Scheme {
   case dark
   case light
}

struct Colors {
   
   let keysDefaultColor: UIColor
   let keysHighlightColor: UIColor
   
   let grayKeysDefaultColor: UIColor
   let grayKeysHighlightColor: UIColor
   
   let buttonTextColor: UIColor
   
   init(colorScheme: Scheme) {
       switch colorScheme {
       case .light:
          
           keysDefaultColor = UIColor.white
           keysHighlightColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
           
           grayKeysDefaultColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
           grayKeysHighlightColor = UIColor.white
           
           buttonTextColor = .black
          
       case .dark:
           
           keysDefaultColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
           keysHighlightColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
           
           grayKeysDefaultColor =  UIColor.darkGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
           grayKeysHighlightColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
           
           buttonTextColor = .white
         
       }
   }
}
```

Then I have a collection view, for the cells I made a custom class. After I declare and setup the collection view (which is scrollable), I create the following function to set its colors:

```swift
    func setColorScheme(_ colorScheme: Scheme) {
        let colorScheme =  Colors(colorScheme: colorScheme)
        
            func setToRootView(view: UIView) {
                if let cell = view as? CustomCells {
                    cell.label.textColor = colorScheme.buttonTextColor
                   
                    cell.defaultColor = colorScheme.keysDefaultColor
                    cell.highlighColor = colorScheme.keysHighlightColor
                    
                    cell.setBackground() //This sets highlight background on tap and default for normal state
                    return
                }
                guard view.subviews.count > 0 else {
                    return
                }
                view.subviews.forEach(setToRootView(view:))
            }
            setToRootView(view: self)
        
}
```

I call this function in the init of the view where I put the collection view and in the keyboard view controller here:

```swift
  override func textDidChange(_ textInput: UITextInput?) {
        // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.
        let colorScheme:  Scheme
        let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy
        if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.dark {
            colorScheme = .dark
        } else {
            colorScheme = .light
    }
        
        myView.setColorScheme(colorScheme)
}
```

cell for item at:

```swift
let cell = myCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "keyboardCellsId", for: indexPath) as! CustomCells
    cell.label.text = String("abc")
    return cell
```

So I think I'm missing something. I know I didn't post the full code but it's because I didn't want to make th question too heavy, If you need more let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share your collectionView `cellForItem` delegate method?

I think you probably have to set the color of cell and buttons in the collectionView `cellForItem` delegate method

The reason it loads correctly the first time is because all visible cells are set to the correct color, however colors may not be set correctly on buttons when showing new cells

Comment: I added  the code to my question! I think you're right

Comment: That's it! I had to set the scheme in my cellForItem. Thank you I was going crazy mad! It tricked me because I only worked with non scrollabe collecton views before and I had to set the scheme just in the init

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help